# Consecutive Integer Sum of an m-member Sequence is Divisible by m Proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, solution-verification, proof-explanation, combinatorial-proofs

This problem is found in Richard A. Brauldi's book on Introductory Combinatorics. It goes as follows:

*Given m integers $a_1, a_2, ... ,a_m$, there exist integers $k$ and $l$ with $0 \le k \lt l \le m$ such that $a_{k+1} + a_{k+2} + ... + a_l$ is divisible by $m$. Less formally, there
exist consecutive $a$'s in the sequence $a_1, a_2, . .. ,a_m$ whose sum is divisible by $m$.*

The author starts the proof like this:

Consider the $m$ sums:

$a_1, a_1 + a_2, a_1 + a_2 + a_3, ..., a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ... + a_m$

If any of these sums are divisible by $m$, then the conclusion holds. Thus, we may suppose that each of these sums has a nonzero remainder when divided by $m$ and so ...

The author then continues with the proof; yet, I haven't understood how it is that we can just *suppose*  that the sums have a nonzero remainder? I at first thought the author was attempting at a proof by contradiction, but the author continues to demonstrate how it is possible to construct with integers $k$ and $l$ the sequence $a_{k + 1}, ..., a_l$, the sum of the terms of which is divisible by $m$. But this doesn't contradict the supposition we've took previously, because we've only considered series beggining with the first term, $a_1$ and not any general sequence. Could anyone elucidate the flaw in my reasoning? That you in advance.

Comment: You do not have to treat that case separately: instead you can consider the remainders on division by $m$ of the $m+1$ sums  $0, a_1, a_1 + a_2, a_1 + a_2 + a_3, \ldots, a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \cdots + a_m$.  By the pigeonhole principle you will find at least two with the same remainder; with such a pair you can subtract the smaller from the larger   to get the desired result.

Comment: I'm  highly interested in the proof (now that your question has been answered by @DanielMathias ), could you at least provide how the author approaches the proof, if not the complete proof itself?

Comment: @DS The author continues: If any of these sums is divisible by m, then the conclusion holds. Thus, we may suppose that each of these sums has a nonzero remainder when divided by m, and so a remainder equal to one of $1,2,...,m–1$. Since there are $m$ sums and only $m−1$ remainders, two of the sums have the same remainder when divided by $m$. Therefore, there are integers $k$ and $l$ with $k<l$ such that $a_1+a_2+...+a_k$ and $a_1+a_2+...+a_l$ have the same remainder $r$ when divided by $m$: $a_1+a_2+...+a_k=bm+r$ $a_1+a_2+...+a_l=cm+r$

Comment: Subtracting, we find that $a_{k+1}+...+a_l=(c–b)m$; thus, $a_{k+1}+...+a_l$ is divisible by $m$. Overall, I believe the book I've found accomplishes it's task in elucidating what's considered fundamental to combinatorics very well. I haven't much experience with combinatorics in general, but the book itself has gave me a priceless foundation. I only read the book as an amateur; judging by, of course, that I'm still in high school and the only combinatorics taught there is really a part of algebra basics (counting combinations and permutations).

Comment: thanks for the reply, although I had figured out something similar :)

Answer (score 3):

> If any of these sums are divisible by $m$, then the conclusion holds.

Because of this, it suffices to prove that the conclusion holds when none of those sums is divisible by $m$, i.e. the remainders are nonzero.

Comment: Ahh, of course, and how under the nose the answer was! Thank you very much for this!